# Change cursor after two clicks using only html and css?

Tags: html, css, cursor, pseudo-class

I know I can change the cursor with one click with the following CSS code:

```
#slide-arrow-prev:active {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Is there anyway to change a cursor after two clicks using *only* html and css? I'm curious if I can do it without using javascript. If so, how please. Thank you

Comment: please check this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78209906/20449015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are determined to not use JS, you can achieve this by having a child as a [focusable element](https://web.dev/learn/html/focus) inside the parent and disabling it's `pointer-events` after the first click. Here is an implementation:

```css
#slide-arrow-prev{
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  background: lavender;
}

#inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#slide-arrow-prev:focus{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#inner:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex=0 id="slide-arrow-prev">
  <div tabindex=0 id='inner'>
    Click Me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of using focusable elements, but it seems to work in this instance! I was trying to avoid JS because I had it tied in with the class heavily already. Aliexpress uses something similar to focusable elements on their home page on their slider arrows, which is what I'm trying to mimic.